# Proving the binomial coefficient identity $\binom{~s + t~ }{s} = \prod_{i=1}^s \prod_{j=1}^t \frac{i + j}{i + j - 1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I tried expanding the factorial, but I do not know how to finish the proof.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{~s + t~ }{s} & = &  \frac{(s+t)!}{s! ~ t!}\\
& = & \frac{(s+t)(s+t-1) \cdots (t+2)(t+1)}{s!} \\
& = & \prod_{i=1}^s \frac{t + i}{i} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

How do I get
$$ \prod_{i=1}^s \frac{t + i}{i} = \prod_{i=1}^s \prod_{j=1}^t \frac{i + j}{i + j - 1}$$?

Comment: Cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition#MacMahon_formula BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Telescopic product. Write a few terms out for $j=1,2,3..$:
$$\frac{i+1}i\cdot\frac{i+2}{i+1}\cdots\frac{i+t}{i+t-1} = \frac{i+t}i$$

Comment: Merci, Berci! I thought something like this would be the case, but had trouble writing it down.

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom{~s + t~ - 1}{s - 1} + \binom{~s + t~ - 1}{s}$$

$$\prod_{i=1}^{s-1} \prod_{j=1}^{t} \frac{i + j}{i + j - 1} + \prod_{i=1}^s \prod_{j=1}^{t-1} \frac{i + j}{i + j - 1}$$

$$\left(\prod_{j=1}^{t} \frac{s + j - 1}{s + j} + \prod_{i=1}^s \frac{i + t - 1}{i + t}\right) \prod_{j=1}^{t} \prod_{i=1}^s \frac{i + j}{i + j - 1}$$

$$\left(\prod_{j=1}^{t} \frac{s + j - 1}{s + j} + \prod_{i=1}^s \frac{i + t - 1}{i + t}\right) \binom{s+t}{s}$$

$$\left(\frac{s}{s + t} + \frac{t}{s + t}\right) \binom{s+t}{s}$$

$$\binom{s+t}{s}$$